# Missing required parameters Laravel 10

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

##### Error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: resto.show] [URI: resto/{resto}]. (View: /vagrant/site/resources/views/resto/index.blade.php)

##### Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Food;
use Illuminate\Support\Composer;

class FoodController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('resto.index' , [
            'foods' => Food::all()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('resto.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
           'food_name' => 'required ' ,
            'food_price' => 'required'
        ]);

        $food = new Food();

        $food->name = strip_tags($request->input('food_name'));
        $food->price = strip_tags($request->input('food_price'));

        $food->save();

        return redirect()->route('resto.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('resto.show' , [
           'food' => Food::find($id)
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

##### Routes (`web.php`)

```php
Route::get('/' , [PageController::class , 'index'])
    ->name('home.index');
Route::get('about' , [PageController::class , 'about'])
    ->name('home.about');
Route::get('contact' , [PageController::class , 'contact'])
    ->name('home.contact');
Route::resource('resto' , 'FoodController');
```

##### Blade view (`index.blade.php`)

```html
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Computers')

@section('section')
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Computers Page
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
        @if(count($computers) > 0)
            <ul>
                @foreach($computers as $computer)
                    <a href="{{ route('computers.show' , ['computer' => $computer['id']]) }}">
                        <li>{{ $computer['name'] }} = {{ $computer['ram'] }} </li>
                    </a>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @else
            <h3>No Computers</h3>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

##### Blade view (`show.blade.php`)

```html
@extends('main')
@section('title', 'Food page')

<style>
    li:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

@section('section')
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Laravel
    </div>
    <p>{{ $food['name'] }}</p>
@endsection
```

It's my first laravel project. I am trying to make a foods menu when a user clicks on foods, it must take him to the food page using the id .

Comment: Which view `index.blade.php` has `resto.show` URL? the one you shared has `computer.show`...

Answer (score -3):

To fix the issue,

here is modified code of index.blade.php:

```
<a href="{{ route('resto.show', ['id' => $computer['id']]) }}">
    <li>{{ $computer['name'] }} = {{ $computer['ram'] }} </li>
</a>
```

update code of show.blade.php:

```
@extends('main')
@section('title', 'Food page')

<style>
    li:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

@section('section')
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Laravel
    </div>
    <p>{{ $food->name }}</p> <!-- Change $food['name'] to $food->name -->
@endsection
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as per the [answer] link. A code-dump answer might help the OP but is of no use to future visitors with similar problems.

Comment: Where did you get `resto.show`? It is not on the view the author shared, how do you know that is the wrong code?